# IF function with blank cell referenced

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I maintain a spreadsheet in which a penalty is assessed when certain benchmarks are not met.

I use the formula below to display the number 8 in cell `S4` if the number in `S3` is below 80, or 0 when 80 or above.  When `S3` is blank, the result in `S4` is 8.  Is there a way to leave a blank result, or not calculate, if `S3` is blank?

```
=IF(S3<80,"8","0")
```

Comment: `=IF(S3="","",IF(S3<80,"8","0"))`

Comment: Is there a reason why you convert the 8 and 0 to text?  Without the quotes, that will still put 8 and 0 in S4.  If you are doing any kind of arithmetic with the numbers, leave out the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments you need to wrap your IF statement into another IF statement creating a **nested IF**.

The resulting statement given in the comments is

`=IF(S3="","",IF(S3<80,"8","0"))`

however as also pointed out you shouldn't use quotes around figures in case you need to use those figures in further calculations so you would need to change that to

`=IF(S3="","",IF(S3<80,8,0))`

Further, especially if you are going to share the spreadsheet and knowing how many times I have come across people entering a space instead of pressing delete or backspace to clear a cell, to prevent problems you could make a further change and put

`=IF(OR(S3="",S3=" "),"",IF(S3<80,8,0))`